# Jenkins - Console Output pretty formatting using RICH api

Tags: python, jenkins, rich

I recently started to use Rich API for python and it feels awesome.
I was wondering if I could get it running somehow to emulate same results in jenkins console output.
I was searching for more information on their github page:
https://github.com/Textualize/rich

But I couldn't find anything helpful.
I also installed on jenkins the AnsiColor plugin but didn't work.

Syntax highlighting seems to work well for console logging, but the colors won't show up.
Does anyone know if I can make this work? Thank you!

Comment: If you are triggering your Jobs externally you may be able to pull this off. You can you Jenkins API library for this. https://pypi.org/project/jenkinsapi/